# How would I mass update date and time?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic, ora-01830

I have to query an update for date and time. I know how to update the date alone, but I am having trouble with adding the time to the function. Right now, as it stands, it reads `4/20/2011 1:32:07 PM`. I need the recv_date field to read `4/21/2011 7:00:00 AM`.

My query so far is:

```
UPDATE cxadmin.ro_hist
   SET recv_date = '4/21/2011'
 WHERE recv_serial_nbr = 'SABTSMSSD'
```

Comment: This would require built-in functions to handle and maipulate date times which isnt a SQL standard and differs across implementation. Please indicate the database type(s) you are using or intend to target.

Answer (score 7):

SQL date formats are notoriously picky, requiring you to use [TO_DATE to ensure that a string representation of a date is converted to an Oracle DATE data type](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

```
UPDATE cxadmin.ro_hist
   SET recv_date = TO_DATE('4/21/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
 WHERE recv_serial_nbr = 'SABTSMSSD'
```

Your example doesn't include the time portion:

```
UPDATE cxadmin.ro_hist
   SET recv_date = TO_DATE('4/21/2011 7:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
 WHERE recv_serial_nbr = 'SABTSMSSD'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
update cxadmin.ro_hist
set recv_date = '4/21/2011 07:00:00 AM'
where recv_serial_nbr ='SABTSMSSD'
```

Comment: wHEN I TRY this way I receive the DB error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @Justin: that's because your default date format doesn't include the time portion. It's safer to use TO_DATE as OMG Ponies has suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Use the to_timestamp('4/21/2011 7:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') instead of TO_DATE